# createQueryBuilder and setParameters() for the same parameter several values

Tags: sql, symfony

When I run this code, the result is only the second value for the same parameter. But I need both role's values - value1 and value2.
My code looks like this:

```
$builder
->add('name', EntityType::class, array(
'class' => 'App:Class',
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $u) {
              return $u->createQueryBuilder('z')
              ->andWhere('z.roles =:role')
              ->setParameters(array('role' => 'value1', 'role' => 'value2'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
 $u->createQueryBuilder('z')
   ->andWhere('z.roles IN (:roles)');
   ->setParameter('roles', array('value1','value2'), \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use something like this:

```
$rolesArray = array('role' => 'value1', 'role' => 'value2');
$queryBuilder = $u->createQueryBuilder('z')
                  ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->in('z.roles', $roles));

return $queryBuilder;
```